# Bitwise operations on a long piece of memory

Tags: c, assembly, bitwise-operators, sse

Is it possible to do bitwise operations `directly` on a long piece of memory (say, 512 bit or even more)?

By `directly` I mean, NOT multiple shifting and watching bounds... as following code.

```
/* 
// shifting 128 bit data [pc2, pc1] to left, 
// and then assigning it to [rc2, rc1]:
*/
uint64_t au1, pc1, pc2, rc1, rc2;
rc1 = pc1 >> 63;\
au1 = pc2 << 1;\
rc2 = rc1 ^ au1;\
rc1 = pc1 << 1;\
```

Comment: Yes and no. Of course it is possible to alloc memory for *numbers* of 512 or 1024 bits, and yes you will be able to do any *operation* on them. But no, ic C you will not be able to write `a+b` with such numbers and will have to use `add(a,b)` (it would be possible in C++...).

Comment: There are libraries available for this like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Is it faster than working with multiple long ints. I mean for example shifting by one bit can be applied one time? (Currently I should 2 times shifting and watching bound bits.)

Comment: @kichik GMP is a heavy library that supports complex calculations. I need some simple bitwise operations. I should try it, but I prefer to write this code my self.

Comment: If you work in C you won't be able to get more than C can do. That means that you can write a function that will process numbers of an arbitrary size, but internally it will only process standard types like int, long and char. That's the way GMP works... Maybe some specialized hardware could do more, or if using assembly language you could make use of *rotate through carry* operations. But in pure C you can only use C types and C operations.

Comment: Assembly language is the way to go to achieve non portable highly optimized low level operations. My advice is write it first in portable C, test it, and if you really need that rewrite some parts in assembly language (after profiling to see where it is most useful).

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thanks! Nice idea. I currently have ~0 knowledge in Assembly. I should learning it now :|

Comment: Without knowledge in Assembly you probably should make sure that you are sure there is a big enough gain in rewriting this in assembly. You should probably look for other possible and perhaps smarter optimizations.

Comment: @skyking: I worked on my C code for months and the only part that can be optimized is the bitwise operations part.

Comment: How much time do your bitwise operation take? I assume that you've turned on compiler optimization of them...

Comment: Assuming you're targetting x86 only, you can perform 128 bit bitwise operations with SSE and 256 bit bitwise operations with AVX. You don't need assembler for this - just use intrinsics with C. XOR is one instruction, and you'll need to build the arithmetic operations for anything longer than 64 bits from XOR and other bitwise operations.

Comment: @PaulR I tested them before, and I wonder why they are slower (on my x64)!

Comment: @u123: are you talking about using SSE/AVX intrinsics ? And when you say "they were slower" - slower than *what* ? In what use case ? It's hard to give you specific answers if you don't provide specific details and code.

Comment: @PaulR Slower than the technique which I detailed in my Q. For example I use four uint64_t to do bitwise operations on a 256 bit number.

Comment: @u123 If you want someone to look at your C code to figure out if it can be sped up, feel free to post it.

Comment: @FUZxxl Code added to Q.

Comment: BEWARE: xor and additions are different operations! Your ADD_P_Q is an xor  not an addition and your MUL_BY_2 is wrong

Comment: There is no need to use macros for this stuff. Inline functions work much better.

Comment: The `typedef` looks wrong. Do you really want `p`, `q` and `r` to be different names for the `struct num128b` struct?

Comment: @SergeBallesta This is not exactly of my code, but why mul2 is wrong?

Comment: I always do silly mistakes.

Comment: Now your `typedef` is pointless...

Comment: One thing one should be aware of is that interfacing with assembler has some overhead. The speed gain in writing tiny parts in assembler could easily be lost in the interface overhead. I doubt that you can gain rewriting 128-bit operations in assembler.

Comment: I don't see any SIMD in your code. If it's slower then probably you have written it incorrectly. Without code it's impossible to tell what's wrong. And don't use macros, use inline functions instead

Comment: @FUZxxl: Thanks. I doubt inline func be better than macro, but I should test.

Comment: Your macros may become slow because you access a global (temporary) variable.

Comment: @skyking: I used au1 multiple times (through other funcs), and I guess if I use a ordinary function the computer should allocates and then free memory for au1, many times. I write the code such that there are no temporary var is exists.

Comment: I think your fear of temporary variables may be unfounded. Have you done any measurements to justify your fear? Often CPU registers will be used for temporary variables and when that's not possible the actual allocation of a local variable does not carry any particular cost (the cost of allocating the stack frame is normally constant no matter how many local variables you have).

Comment: @PaulR Please take a look at compare code. It is the code which i compare two techniques.

Comment: @u123: you need to also specify how you built the test code (which compiler, what optimisation switches were used, etc). E.g. if you compiled without optimisation enabled then the results are meaningless. You should also look at the generated code for the scalar implementation and see if the compiler is doing any auto-vectorization.

Comment: @PaulR I updated code, it is with gcc -O2. I do not understand the other part of your comment (scalar implementation and auto-vectorization). I am not an expert in C!

Comment: @u123 this means that you write your code in usual C and let the compiler turn it into SSE code. Add `-ftree-vectorize`, `-mavx` (or whatever your target HW platform is) to your compiler flags.

Comment: And if you also add `-fopt-info-vec-optimized-missed` to the above flags then gcc will also report to you, which parts of your code it was able to turn into simd.

Comment: With all above flags SSE technique  is slower.

Comment: You need to take more care when measuring the difference. For example the loops in your code can be optimized away - I get TIME1=TIME2=0.

Comment: You should probably include the context in which these operation will be performed. As pointed out rewriting just `bitshift_left` in assembler will probably not provide any gain (in fact using your test it would loose performance since the compiler won't be able to optimize away the loops anymore).

Comment: @skyking I just want to compare speed of mm_bitshift_left vs method1. Hence, I do not want compiler optimizes loops.

Comment: Then you must take care to make sure that opportunity does not exist, otherwise the compiler may easily do so if you enable optimizations. As pointed out comparing the result without optimizations is quite pointless.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#cats=Bit%20Manipulation,Logical

Comment: One reason your question is unclear is that it lacks context. How you are going to use these operations is not mentioned. Exactly what are you trying to do? Have you done proper measurement to identify that it's actually these operations that are the performance problem in the first place? How did you measure that?

Comment: The answer to your edited question is no.  The widest elements for SSE/AVX bitwise shift operations are 64 bits.  You have to do something like what you wrote to carry bits across element boundaries for extended-precision shifts.  I think you can do it more efficiently with AVX2 than scalar, but it takes multiple vector shift and OR operations.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks! Your comment is among a few useful and clear comments here.

Comment: It's not a coincidence that it only came after your last clarification to the question.  I had looked at it previously and wasn't sure exactly what you wanted to know.

Comment: The first version of my question is almost as this version by in argue with people I placed some unnecessary information!